# Inserting passwords to database, any difference with a regular text field?

Tags: php, mysql, passwords

I'm making a registration form, my only doubt is how to handle passwords (how to insert them into MySQL database). I don't have the slightest idea on how to do it, what type of column must `Passwords` be, whether I must encrypt them somehow, etc. Could you provide a basic example with explanation so that I manage to do it?

Comment: char\varchar and should be hashed and salted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to store the password as-is in plaintext. You don't even want to be able to know what the password is. Therefore, you store a hash of the password in your database. When the user wants to log in, you hash the password he's trying to login with, then compare that to the hash in the database. Any serious password storage system furthermore salts the hash to prevent rainbow table attacks against the password (google that). Since this is a rather complex topic and you apparently have no experience with it at all, I recommend you use [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) to hash and salt your passwords without worrying about the implementation details. The phpass site also has some good introductory articles about the topic. [Here's another one](http://dev.myunv.com/articles/secure-passwords-with-phpass/) that keeps it really simple.

As for the database, that'll just be a normal `VARCHAR` field long enough to hold the hash.

Answer (score 1):

Read this: http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/

Then do this: http://www.openwall.com/phpass/

Answer (score 0):

You should not store password, password hash only. 
Database type should be choose after you will choose hasfunction.
For `md5`/`sha512` it will be char(32) if you will keep hex representation

Query is something like this:

```
"INSERT INTO users SET otherFields,pass_hash='".hashFunc($_POST['password']."';
```

where hashFunc generates hash ex

```
function hashFunc($pass){
    $salt='something';
    md5($salt . $pass);
}
```

Comment: While this isn't the best answer, it didn't deserve a downvote. +1

Comment: If storing passwords in plaintext is like leaving the door wide open, MD5 is like closing the door. It looks secure right up until a thief opens it. Stop recommending MD5. Use bcrypt.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to safely secure a password is using a Moore's Law-defeating hash function. Use [bcrypt](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/)!

Answer (score -1):

One of the ways it can be done is by using md5. You convert the password to md5 and put it in the database (md5 encryption is one-way) when the user logs in again you convert the filled in password again and check if the converted password is somewhere to be found in your database (in combination with a username usually).

**EDIT**

You can make a string into an md5 string with this:

```
$converted_pass = md5($unconverted_pass);
```

However you will need to add a so called salt-key to the password before you encrypt it with md5. This is a set of letters/numbers etc. If you do this every time you will have the same result but it will be quite safe :)

Comment: if you don't salt it you may as well store as plain text

Comment: That's true. Sorry, forgot that =( You need to salt it indeed.